# Как быть, не хчоет запускаться код через cmd?

Tags: python

```
C:\Python>math2.py
```

> Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\VERA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe "C:\Python\math2.py" '

как быть?

Answer (score 3):

Через cd откройте директорию,где лежит файл, или укажите путь к нему уже в самой команде

```
python math2.py
```

Comment: не совсем понял(могли бы написать, что такое директория?) Мой путь к файлам Python: cd C:\Python

Comment: директория = папка, если ваш файл лежит в C:\Python, то вы правильно написали, сначала cd C:\Python, потом команда, которую указана в ответе

Comment: пишет то, что python3 не является внутреннем или внешнем файлом

Comment: это проблема со всеми моими работами

Comment: Если у вас windows 10, то придётся её скачать через, местные магазин, windows store, вроде, так называется

Comment: у меня Windows 7

Comment: пишу код через Subliem text и проверяю на cdm, но после установки патча pyowm все накрылось

Comment: также во время установки просили разрешение на какие-то изменения и  я нечайно один раз дал отказ

Comment: и все накрылось

Comment: попробуйте установить IDE, Pycharm, например

Comment: а как?(я новенький)

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

Comment: а что делать, если мне приятнее на сублайм текст работать, что это за ошибка с открытием файла?

Comment: Гугл в помощь, друг мой

Comment: как видишь, если я тут, значит гугл не особо-то и помог

Comment: @JackWolf, `python3 math2.py` не будет работать под Windows, если специально не пойти переименовать исполняемый файл из python.exe в python3.exe. По-умолчанию для любой версии Python он python.exe.

Comment: @insolortiredofthisdrama еще можно не переименовывать а создать сим\хард линк или указать алиас =)